# FastAPI add additional argument to running Uvicorn

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, fastapi, argparse, uvicorn

I'm currently starting up the server with the following Uvicorn command:

```
main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8003 --access-log
```

And I would like to add an extra argument `--foo` such that it works as [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/argparse.html#action)'s "store_true" action so I can optionally execute a function during my startup.

With Python, using argparse I can achieve this executing the command `main.py --migrate`:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Startup")
parser.add_argument("--foo", dest="run_foo", action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    if args.run_foo:
        foo()
```

Where `app` is my FastAPI instance. However, I get an `uvicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8003 --access-log` when I try to execute it using Uvicorn. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you please explain more what you are asking?  It sounds like you want to extend the Uvicorn CLI by using argparse...?  Is that right?

Comment: @Alexander yes and no. I posted my Python solution which uses argparse, but I don't know if something similar could be done in Uvicorn. So yes, I imagine this would be considered expanding the CLI.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing... Using environment variables can be a workaround

Answer (score 3):

You can do a trick by calling your service in python and using `argparse` as:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
import argparse
app: FastAPI = FastAPI()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    foo(args.foo)
    #run server
    uvicorn.run(app)
```

Then run you server using normal python command and pass the argument:

```
python main.py --foo foo
```

Comment: abvious not op want to do....

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to define the environment variables of uvicorn app and get them through Python. I recommend this amazing tutorial that will explain it better than me. But if you are lazy to read or prefer a TL;DR explanation, here it goes:

You can configure environment variables with `ADMIN_EMAIL="deadpool@example.com" APP_NAME="ChimichangApp" uvicorn main:app` (for example). And then get the variable from your Python app using:

```
import os
name = os.getenv("ADMIN_EMAIL")
print(f"The email is {ADMIN_EMAIL}")
```

However, this are not best practices. First of all, it would be better to define the env variables with a `*.env` file, and use it with `uvicorn main:app --env-file <my-filename>.env`. This env file will look like this:

```
ADMIN_EMAIL="deadpool@example.com"
APP_NAME="ChimichangApp"
```

Secondly, it would be better to use pydantic to get the env variables.